# stackcpp - An asynchronous C++11 library for the StackExchange API

Tags: library, api-v2.2, c++

stackcpp is an asynchronous C++11 library for the StackExchange API!

#### Code Snippet

Here's a small example of the API in action:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stackcpp/client.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << "Input a user id: ";

    stackcpp::unique_id user_id;
    std::cin >> user_id;

    // You need to replace 'api_key' by a valid API key.
    const stackcpp::client client{"api_key"};

    const auto user = client.users(user_id).get();
    std::cout << user.name() << " has " << user.reputation() << " reputation!\n";
}
```

Note that while this example doesn't use filters, it is highly recommended that you should.

#### Download / Install

You can head over to [github](https://github.com/rakete1111/stackcpp) and either download the source and build it yourself, or download the pre-built libraries.

#### Platform

stackcpp supports every platform that has a conforming C++11 compiler and Boost support. As of right now, this doesn't include Windows, as its `<future>` implementation isn't fully done.

#### Contact

If you have any bugs or feature requests, you can head over to [github](https://github.com/rakete1111/stackcpp) and post them there.

Alternatively, bugs can also be reported here in form of "answers".

If you have any general questions, you can comment here or go to IRC freenode #stackcpp (although I can't guarantee that I'll be online 24/7, so commenting is the better option in my opinion).